# How to calculate the ground state molecular potential curve of Lithium in different spin configuration?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecules, intermolecular-forces

I am a physics student and interested in Atom, and molecule optical physics. I am studying Feshbach resonance and I need to know the potential curve of the molecule, then I ask question in physics stack exchange but I could not get any reply.

[image]

I saw the above picture on the German Wikipedia of Feshbach resonance. They mentioned the ground state of Lithium diatomic molecule($Li_2$) has this the molecular potential curve in different spin configuration($S=0,S=1$).

However because I am not familiar with the molecular physics and quantum chemistry, I don't understand how I can calculate/simulate them out. If someone can provide me some information, or list the formula(Hamiltonian), I will have some directions of this issue.

Thank you

Comment: What is 'the lithium molecule'?

Comment: @isolatedmatrix diatomic molecule of Lithium

Comment: The LI$_2$ molecule has been well studied, the potential energy curves  should be in this reference,   I. Schmidt-Mink, W. Muller, and W. Meyer, Chem. Phys. 92, 263 (1985).

Comment: @porphyrin Thanks for the information.